# Trying to create a new window with the information from a form that I can customize. Stuck

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, document.write

I am working on a website for a friend of a friend, and the biggest thing I am stuck on currently is the adoption form. I have the form all said an done, but I cannot get the input information to open on a new page. A print screen so to speak that only includes the questions and the inputted answers. I had a very simple code which worked out fine. It popped up with exactly what I wanted printed. Problem is that I could not customize it with CSS. I found another way of doing it from a help question on here. But this person who asked the question isn't doing the same thing I am so it only helps so much.

This is the code I tried that worked fine but wasn't customizable:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function printDiv(divName) {
 alert('s');
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 w=window.open();
 w.document.write(printContents);
 w.print();
 w.close();
}
```

```html
For specific area of a page
<div id="print-content">
 <form>

  <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!"/>
</form>
</div>
```

This is another code I also tried, which didn't work at all:

```js
function printPage(){
        var width = screen.width - 50;
        var tableData = '<table width="'+width+'" border="1">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'</table>';

        var cssHead = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></head>'

        var data = cssHead + '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;     
        myWindow=window.open('','','width=auto,height=auto');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
    };
```

Nothing happened after this. I clicked the button and absolutely nothing happened.

Then I tried taking a little bit of both:

```js
function printDiv(divName) {


var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
var cssHead = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></head>'


var data = cssHead + printContents;

 myWindow=window.open('','','width=auto,height=auto');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
 myWIndow.close();
}
```

This also did not work. Clicked the button nothing happened. I am at a horrible loss for what to do. I know some JavaScript but not a lot. I was exposed to it a bit in school. Nothing advanced. I really want to get this done and it is one of the last things before it's finished. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, this may help you

include stylesheet in in your first javascript with media="print".

also see this link, that may help you

[Print/Preview Ignoring my Print.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612794/print-preview-ignoring-my-print-css)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printDiv() {


var printContents = document.getElementById("myForm");
var cssHead = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></head>'


var data = cssHead +printContents;

 myWindow=window.open('','','width=auto,height=auto');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
        myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

```css
.form-style-1 {
     
     margin:10px auto;
     max-width: 1100px;
     padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;

     background-color: #ccebff;
}
.form-style-1 li {
     padding: 5px;
     display: block;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
     background-color: transparent;
}
.form-style-1 label{
     margin:0 0 3px 0;
     padding:0px;
     display:block;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #4db8ff;
     
}
.form-style-1 input[type=text], 
.form-style-1 input[type=date],
.form-style-1 input[type=datetime],
.form-style-1 input[type=number],
.form-style-1 input[type=search],
.form-style-1 input[type=time],
.form-style-1 input[type=url],
.form-style-1 input[type=email],
 textarea, 
 select{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     border:1px solid #BEBEBE;
     padding: 7px;
     margin:0px;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
     outline: none;  
}
.form-style-1 input[type=text]:focus, 
.form-style-1 input[type=date]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=datetime]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=number]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=search]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=time]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=url]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=email]:focus,
.form-style-1 textarea:focus, 
.form-style-1 select:focus{
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
     box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
     border: 1px solid #88D5E9;
}
.form-style-1 .field-divided{
     width: 20%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-divided2{
     width: 152px;
}

.form-style-1 .field-long{
     width: 20%;
}
.form-style-1 .field-select{
     width: 8%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-select2{
     width: 100px;
}

.form-style-1 .field-textarea{
     height: 80px;
}
.form-style-1 input[type=submit], .form-style-1 input[type=button]{
     background: #4B99AD;
     padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
     border: none;
     color: #fff;
}
.form-style-1 input[type=submit]:hover, .form-style-1 input[type=button]:hover{
     background: #4691A4;
     box-shadow:none;
     -moz-box-shadow:none;
     -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}
.form-style-1 .required{
     color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="frminfo">
<form method="post" id="myform" enctype="text/plain"> 
<ul class="form-style-1">
```

That didn't work at all let me try this again. I am going to post the form input I want to print, the javascript I'm using and the button onClick event. I Have also included the css already affecting the form. I click the print button which should trigger the onClick event but nothing happens. I can't figure this out. Have been stuck for weeks.

I can no longer even get the function to work never mind the css trying to customize it.