# How to add CSS file to print()

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen a couple answers to this but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have a function to print a grid, but the CSS doesn't transfer over ( unless I manually add in a style ). How do I add a CSS file? I've tried:

```
$("#btn").click(function (e) {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById("expertiseTable");
        newWin = window.open("");
        //var myStyle = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:59840/Content/Site.css" />';
        newWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:59840/Content/Site.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
        newWin.print();
});
```

Placing http://localhost:59840/Content/Site.css into the broswer brings up my CSS file so I know its there, but when I try to print it doesn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Did yout tried something like,

```
newWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:59840/Content/Site.css" media="print" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612794/print-preview-ignoring-my-print-css).

I placed the `media="print"` attribute.

There is also the option of the `@media print` usage,

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{
        .aClass { display: none; }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: yeah i tried that, it just brings up the contents and no CSS

Comment: Specifying `media="print"` will simply _limit_ the stylesheet to be used strictly for print. By omitting the `media` attribute, as Keith already did, it will fall back to the default value `all` - which includes `print` anyways.

Comment: Reading about the `media` attibute [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp), you are correct.