# How to embed css styling into print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problem embedding css styling into my Print Preview page.
This is how my index.html looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>My App</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
                  rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app" style="position: absolute;
                                height: 100%;
                                width: 100%;
                                left: 0%; 
                                top: 0%;">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The styles works fine here on index.html but not here when I want to create a new Page for Printing:

```
  alternativePrint(resultId: string){ // Assuming that resultId is unique.
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=800,width=1240');

    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');

    printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();

    return true;
  }

  call(tel:string){
    window.open('tel:'+tel);
  }
```

Print Preview showing blank unless I remove this part:

```
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">');
```

I also tried to give the href as href="http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css" which I can access the css code when i type in url.

update: 
something like this also works fine:

```
printWindow.document.write('<style>h1{color:red}</style>');
```

Comment: Just for kicks, try putting the full HTTP path to the CSS file in the `link` element.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I just tried, still not working showing blank page, when I comment it out the conent shows but ofc with lack of styling.

Comment: Have you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612794/print-preview-ignoring-my-print-css

Comment: @FrancoFusaro that seems some kind of solution but I think it would require quite a change, I might first look why this can't be done from the client side directly since it is an issue of html css javascript.

Comment: I just noticed that in firefox works perfectly fine, but not in Chrome,

Comment: also noticed this msg: [Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML Imports is deprecated. Please refer to .. for possible migration paths.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should change the link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
```

with the ".", or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
```

without the "/".

Comment: Why do you "guess" that? `.` is not a replacement for `/`.